# Enabled condition not working

Tags: installshield

I have a property called: DBSERVERNAME, this is tied to my edit box like this:

[image]

Now I want the "next" button to be disabled, if that textbox is empty, and the underlying variable DBSERVERNAME has no value.

So I created a condition like this :

[image]

But nothing happens, how can I ensure that the button is disabled if the DBSERVERNAME property has no value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Control Conditions like this are best specified in pairs. Think of it like a series of conditions and actions. So your highlighted condition will sometimes enable the control, but nothing will ever disable it.

You need to add a Disable control condition with the complementary condition `Not DBSERVERNAME`. While you're there, I would suggest replacing `DBSERVERNAME<>""` with just `DBSERVERNAME`, as an empty property evaluates as false, and a non-empty property evaluates as true.

Note that if you extend your scenario to cover multiple properties, you will want to combine them into a condition for a single Enable control condition, rather than adding multiple control conditions, to avoid enabling the control when only one of several required conditions are met.

Comment: Perfect, this worked exactly as you described it would.

Comment: One small question is it possible to get the properties to update on keypress, not on blur?

Comment: Nope; the Windows Installer built-in UI is kinda limiting, and unfortunately external UIs (your only other option) are typically way too much work, and/or limiting in other ways.